# PHP MySQL Function Displaying in HTML

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have the function:

```
function get_current_users($current_users) 
{
global $db;
$current_users = $db->EscapeString($current_users);
$total_current_users = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS total_current_users");
return $total_current_users['total_current_users'];
```

}

But I have no clue how to output the result, I've tried the following options but nothing displays:

```
 `<?$total_current_users?>
 <?['$total_current_users']?>
 <?=data['$total_current_users']?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that your function does what it's supposed to, I guess the two equivalent methods would gain you the output:

`<?= get_current_users() ?>` or
`<?php echo get_current_users() ?>`

As a note: I don't see the point of your argument `$current_users` that you escape -- because it never gets use in the subsequent query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
$total_current_users = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT COUNT(*) as total_current_users FROM users");
```

You are selecting one value from inside the result set to return, this value isn't named, try the above to get it to match your code.

then change the template code to be: `<?php echo $total_current_users; ?>`

Comment: When I use that syntax in my functions.php the site just shows blank, if there any way to format that like my example above using a function?

Comment: Before changing anything, we should see what your function is doing, please, in your function, before the `return`add `var_dump($total_current_users);` this should tell you if the query is doing anything at all.